# how can i set kubectl scale deployment into deployment file?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

After setup my kubernetes cluster on GCP i used command **kubectl scale deployment superappip--replicas=30** from google console to scale my deployments, but what should be added in my deployment  file myip-service.yaml to do the same?

Comment: kubernetes uses declarative api. so set `replicas: 30` in deployment.

Comment: spec:
  replicas: 3
#  clusterIP: 10.3.246.114
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - nodePort: 31601
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5000
.... error validating "deployment/myip-service.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Service.spec): unknown field "replicas" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.ServiceSpec; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

Comment: The `replicas:` setting is on the _Deployment_ object, not the Service.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an example of a Deployment. It creates a ReplicaSet to bring up three nginx Pods

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

you can follow more [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment).